# using galaxy tab as a bluetooth device for mobile

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, bluetooth, samsung-galaxy-tab-3-10.1, samsung-galaxy-s-5, samsung-galaxy-gear

i've been trying to find a way to allow all my notifications and phone calls from my phone ( galaxy s3 or galaxy s5) to go through a galaxy tablet, as i'm wanting to replace my car stereo ( honda civic 2007)  with the tablet and i'm wanting to be able to control my phone from the tablet and stream music from the phone. the closest thing i can think of that does this is the galaxy gear watch so can we put the capabilities of the gear in the tab.

below is a list of things i wish to have.

- Hands free
- music sync or transfer
- control music
- allow the use of my data from my phone ( i know i can tether but i just thought i would mention it
- make calls
- view contacts from phone
- use maps

I really do think this is possible, so if anyone has any thoughts if this is possible then please help me out.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to understand, that Bluetooth is based on a [master-slave structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master-slave_%28technology%29), and so are it's drivers and protocol stack.

Most of operations you have specified use existing Bluetooth protocols and profiles:

- hands free => [HFP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Hands-Free_Profile_.28HFP.29)
- music streaming => [A2DP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Advanced_Audio_Distribution_Profile_.28A2DP.29)
- music control => [AVRCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Audio.2FVideo_Remote_Control_Profile_.28AVRCP.29)
- tethering => [BNEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_protocols#Bluetooth_network_encapsulation_protocol_.28BNEP.29)
- making calls = [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_protocols#Telephony_control_protocol_.28TCP.29)
- contact viewing => [PBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Phone_Book_Access_Profile_.28PBAP.2C_PBA.29)

The problem is, the tablet can act as a *master* for these protocols, but is missing the stack and drivers for *slave functionality*. You can, for example, connect the tablet (master) to a headset (slave) over HFP, but you can't use the tablet as a headset.

Until someone develops a more complete *Bluetooth stack for Android*, which includes both master and slave profiles, you can't do this over Bluetooth.